# Second function in unit testing isn't running

Tags: python-3.x, unit-testing

I am doing this simple unittesting and I am a newbie to python.  Heres the code

```
caplet.py
    
def capeach(text):
        return text.capitalize()
```

and the unit testing code is below.

```
UT.py

import unittest
import caplet


class TestCap(unittest.TestCase):
    
    def test_one_word(self):
        text = 'python'
        result = caplet.capeach(text)
        self.assertEqual(result,'Python')

    def multiple_words(self):
        text = 'python is good'
        result = caplet.capeach(text)
        self.assertEqual(result,'Python Is Good')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

When I run `UT.py`, I get `Ran 1 test in 0.001s`. Somehow second part of the code `multiple_words` is not running.

I am using Spyder IDE for running the code.  I also tried with the command line `python3 UT.py`

I don't know what I am missing. Can anyone help. Thank you.

Comment: All test method names must start with `"test"` to be executed by the unittest test runner.

Comment: @schwobaseggl I didn't notice that. Thank you. It works perfectly now